# Can I control just a ceiling fan light kit with the switch and leave the fan powered?

Tags: electrical, light-fixture, ceiling-fan

Is this easy to wire to make it work like that? What would I have to do? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of the fan and switch boxes involved please?

Comment: Are you actually in Chicago? Because if so, your wiring is almost definitely in conduit, in which case if an extra wire is needed to make this work it won't be a crazy task to do that.

Comment: Is the fan and light the same device or two separate things? I've seen fan/light combos that are actually one device and you have to control that on the device itself and not from the switch if you want only one part of it on.

Comment: Yeah seriously. "I am in Chicagoland" is a hugely important factor in your question (i.e. ease of doing this).  Most of Chicagoland has metal conduit instead of cables.  So if you don't have the right wires in the walls, you can add them super easy.

Comment: a smart bulb, or just a bulb that comes with a remote (GE started making them in a line of semi-smart bulbs) can remedy this easily, if doing it "for real" is complex.

Comment: I have not taken the light down yet and opened it up. The wiring here has been crazy in the past so I take things slow. I am in Chicago but not an electrician by any means. 
Yes this is for a ceiling fan with lights. 
Thanks for all the responses! I’m new to this site!

Answer (score 1):

As others have said you could add the extra wiring which should be fairly easy given the wiring is in conduit.

An alternate option would be to leave the wiring mostly as is and simply add a ceiling fan remote control. You can by one for $20-30. These come in two parts. The part that you insert in the ceiling fan that sits between the switch and the fan/light and the remote. The are sold as generic units that work with almost all ceiling fans/lights.

Even with conduit adding the remote is probably easier and meets the requirement of allowing you to individually control the fan and light.

Comment: How would I go about adding the wire and what would I connect to what?

Comment: The link below is a pretty good explanation. You are looking at the wiring with separate switch (option 5). Option 6 (the remote fan) will be easier, cost the same, and likely to be more useful in the long run. All of the fan/light combos in bedrooms in my house are wired this way. This allows you to control the fan/light from bed. Handy if you need to adjust the fan speed in the middle of the night. https://www.homedepot.com/c/ah/how-to-wire-a-ceiling-fan/9ba683603be9fa5395fab901d170dd47